# What is wrong with this Python Validation code?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a maths quiz with Python and to do this I wanted to make a validation rule that meant if a user put something that was not a number, it will ask them again as it is invalid.

I tried to do this and I am coming up with the same error as I would if I did it normally. Any help?

```
if operator=="+":
   #this is a if statement which states that if the operator is
  #add then the answer should be num1 add num2 as the add function was     randomly
    #picked
    def inputNumber(message):
        while True:
            try:
                useranswer=int(input(actualquestion))
            except ValueError:
                print("This is not an integar!")
                continue
            else:
                 return usseranswer
                 break
actualanswer=num1 + num2 #this states that the answer is equal to the rando
#ly picked num1 add num2 as the operator is add.
if useranswer==actualanswer:
    #this if function states that if the users answer is equal to the real answer
    #the programme worked out before hand.
    score+=1 #if the answer is right you will add 1 to the score
    questions+= 1 #you will add 1 to the question also as 1 qw has been asked.
```

Comment: "I am coming up with the same error"

And that error is?

Answer (score 1):

Your function would normally go at the top of your other code and would not need to be indented:

```
def inputNumber(message):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not an integer!")

result = inputNumber("Please enter a number: ")
print(result)
```

For example the following should do what you need:

```
Please enter a number: hello
This is not an integer!
Please enter a number: 123
123
```